# Does jewel sometimes have a negative meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In the lyrics of song *Sorry* by Halsey there's this line:

> I've missed your calls for months it seems
>
> Don't realise how mean I can be
>
> 'Cause I can sometimes treat the people
> that I love like **jewelry**

Jewelry is a good and prestigious thing. Why does someone say I am a mean person for treating loved people like jewelry?

My thought is that since jewelry makes the wearer more beautiful the wearer loves it for srlfish reasons. So I think the same applies here. It means they love people for selfish reasons, not for the sake of those people.

Am I right or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is right. You treat people as if they were your accessories. You are at the centre. I wouldn't call that love, though...

Comment: Although quite interesting, the question isn't really about the English language it's about interpretation. Often lyrics are open to interpretation, how a person reacts to a line will be different to another person. I personally do not care that much about jewellery, the more expensive and larger they are, the more I find them ostentatious. But someone else can prize their private collection, desire to increase their size and value (greed). Or simply spend hours admiring trinkets and precious stones because they find them attractive and/or appreciate their rarity

Comment: Jewelry is not the best way to show off. For example, [Bling-bling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bling-bling)  is flashy jewelry worn especially as an indication of wealth or status; broadly: expensive and ostentatious possessions such as grills and designer bags.

Comment: Jewelry can be very expensive and precious, or much less so, selected because it goes with a particular outfit or season. Some items may thus be forgotten, or put away—paid little  attention to, at least for a time. Even discarded, when the purpose has been served.

Answer (score 1):

*"Jewelry is a good and prestigious thing"*
Only in the eyes of some. To others is is showy, tawdry and often over-used in poor taste. The more jewellery worn, the cheaper and less prestigious the wearer looks.

You can also wear it one day, then drop it in a drawer… that's more likely what the lyric hints at.